# How to properly add new records to empty recordset manually?

Tags: vb6, ado

How to add new records to a new & empty ADODB.Recordset manually?

Right now, here's what I'm doing that isn't working:

```
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open
Dim Fields() as String
Fields(0) = "SomeFieldName"

Dim Values() as String
Value(0) = "SomeValue"

rs.AddNew Fields, Values
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In-place:

```
rs.AddNew "SomeFieldName", "SomeValue"
```

Or in-place multiple fields

```
rs.AddNew Array("SomeFieldName", "AnotherFieldName"), Array("SomeValue", 1234)
```

Or using separate vars

```
Dim Fields As Variant
Dim Values As Variant

Fields = Array("SomeFieldName")
Values = Array("SomeValue")
rs.AddNew Fields, Values
```

Edit: This is how to synthesize a recordset for the AddNew sample above

```
Set rs = new Recordset
rs.Fields.Append "SomeFieldName", adVarChar, 1000, adFldIsNullable
rs.Fields.Append "AnotherFieldName", adInteger, , adFldIsNullable
rs.Open
```

I'm usually using a helper function `CreateRecordset` as seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217021/generating-excel-files-with-vb6/1218745#1218745).

**Update 2018-11-12**

You can also use field indexes as ordinals instead of field names as strings for the fields array like this

```
rs.AddNew Array(0, 1), Array("SomeValue", 1234)
```

Comment: Could you include the declaration and preparation of the recordset prior to the addnew() call? I want to make sure that I'm doing all that needs to be done, no more and no less.

Comment: What would be the best way to execute an SQL statement on the recordset, after the AddNew update?

Comment: @LoBellin This synthetic client-side recordset is not persisted in a RDBMS. Think of it as a glorified 2D array. It's not possible to execute any SQL as there is no RDBMS.

Answer (score 6):

```
set rs = new ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "Select SomeFieldName, AnotherFieldName FROM MyTable", myConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

rs.AddNew
rs("SomeFieldName").Value = "SomeValue"
rs("AnotherFieldName").Value = 1
rs.Update

rs.AddNew
rs("SomeFieldName").Value = "AnotherValue"
rs("AnotherFieldName").Value = 2
rs.Update

rs.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

With an open connection Conn:

```
sSql="INSERT into mytable (somefieldname, anotherfieldname) values  ('Somevalue','Anothervalue')"
      Conn.Execute sSql
```